# Expiry time on php openssl?

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, php-openssl

I'm not very familiar with encryption, and we are now using PHP's openssl_encrypt/decrypt in our application.

Is it possible to make the encryption/decryption work only before an expiry time? e.g. maybe the keys expire?

Comment: Best asked on Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you have to append the creation timestamp as bytes before what you need to encrypt:

```
$time = pack('N', time());
$enc = openssl_encrypt($time . $other_data, ...);
```

When you decrypt:

```
$dec = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, ...);
$time = unpack('N', substr($dec, 0, 4));
$other_data = substr($dec, 4);
if (time() - $time[1] > $EXPIRY_SECONDS)
   die('Expired');
```

The N flag i've used in pack/unpack is for Big Endian byte order, you can also use V for little endian or L for machine-dependent, because the timestamp fit in 32 bit integer (4 bytes).

Comment: hmm.. the reason we needed to use encryption was because the data was being passed from party A to party B, and party B shouldn't be able to open the data at all if it's expired. In this solution, they could have just ignored the first 4 bytes whether it's expired or not.

Comment: That is not possible because if the second party has the correct key, it will be always able to decrypt. Also if the key is somehow related to the actual local time they could fake the system clock (and you are also losing entropy bits for the key)

Comment: If you have to protect a resource such as a licensing system it is really complex and anyway is never impossible to crack. It is better that you store the resource for them and let them download until it expires if it is possible. However big companies like Netflix use DRM systems (Digital Right Management) that forces programs to do not make copies and store undecrypted version on HDD. But as always being a client-side check it can be bypassed